# Change WooCommerce "on-hold" orders to a custom status for specific products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, arguments, orders

I need help with this code, where I need it to change the order status to "customstatus" from "on-hold" status, if it includes a particular product with id - 19345.

I have already created this "customstatus" and I am using a ACH payment gateway which put orders on hold.

My code which is giving me an error when I am trying to pay

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wc_put_order_onhold', 10, 3 );
function wc_put_order_onhold( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    $product_ids   = array('19345');
    $product_found = true;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( ! array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
            $product_found = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $product_found ? 'customstatus' : $status;
}
```

Comment: Some feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code as the hooked functions has only 2 arguments

**There are 2 cases:**

For orders that have **exclusively** items **only** from specific products

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'change_order_status_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function change_order_status_conditionally( $order_id, $order ) {
    $product_ids  = array('19345'); // <== Here define your targeted products
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( ! array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
            return $status;
        }
    }
    return 'customstatus';
}
```

For orders that have at least an item from specific products *(**non exclusively**)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'change_order_status_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function change_order_status_conditionally( $order_id, $order ) {
    $product_ids = array('19345'); // <== Here define your targeted products
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
            return 'customstatus';
        }
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.